# window.open() throws error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression:"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, syntax-error

window.open() suddenly started throwing an "Unrecognised Expression" when being called in a function containing just it. I've tried changing URL, and the Javascript file that the function is in to no avail. Has anyone else experienced this? I'm using the latest JQuery CDN, and it's loading well above the Javascript files.

Code:

```
function spotify() {
    window.open("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://www.google.com
Stack trace:

E</oe.error@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:12961
E</oe.tokenize@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:18940
E</oe.select@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:21833
oe@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:6808
find@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:24398
w.fn.init@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:24883
w@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:896
open@http://localhost:8888/cobalt/classes/js/room.js:56:5
spotify@http://localhost:8888/cobalt/classes/js/spotify-importer.js:82:9
onclick@http://localhost:8888/cobalt/view.php?id=2:1:1
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using proper quotes in your code and not some “smart quotes” that aren't recognized as such? Does changing that address change the resulting error, or is that just coincidental?

Comment: as tadman says, the error indicates javascript is trying to interpret the url as javascript code -- are you running this through an eval() or some such?

Comment: Just tried replacing them with copied & pasted notepad quotes, no effect though.

Comment: Also just tried using `var url = "https://www.google.com/";` and then `window.open(url);` with no change either.

Comment: in the console, once you get the error, type `window.open+''` - is it "native code"?

Comment: That returns the response `"function open(id) {
    $(id).contextMenu(menu,{triggerOn:'click'});
}". Totally random function in a random file, once removed it fixed the problem! Thanks for the help, @JaromandaX I'd _never_ have worked that one out on my own!

Comment: You have to be careful with functions created in the global context - they tend to "override" `window` methods :p

Answer (score 0):

your function is working just fine, you dont even need jquery for that. Try it without the loading jquery.

Comment: Already solved, so I'll leave the solution for others. Thanks for your help!

**This was solved by searching for a rouge function using [window.open+''] in the console. Once found, I removed the function and the code was working again.**

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by searching for a rogue function using `window.open+''` in the debugging console, after running the function that threw the syntax error. Once found, I removed the function, and the code was working again.

The function causing the issue was:

```
function open(id) { $(id).contextMenu(menu,{triggerOn:'click'}); }
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem in the code? It's not clear how someone else with a similar problem would use this answer as a solution. I'm not even sure what it means.

Comment: What's the reason for the square brackets?